# how to show card view like ecommerce website in AngularJS with ng-table and web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ngtable

I want to use ng-table to show products like any ecommerce website so that filters etc can be handled by ng-table.

Please suggest how can i achieve this using ng-table or suggest any other way to do this.

Comment: One of the best way http://ngcart.snapjay.com/. Filters are not specified like for ng-tables. You can use filter in any expression.

Comment: but is there any way to do with ng-table? can we show card view for items using ng-table?

Comment: Yes obviously you can build cart in ng-table. But It is not compulsory to make your cart in ng-table and only then filters will work. Your cart may be build in bootstrap / HTML 5. Filter will work without ng-table as well. I suggest you to read more from angular docs and re ask your question.

Comment: i dont need cart, by card view i mean display of products. e.g. have a look at http://www.lyst.com/shop/mens-sandals/ i want similar design, with filters and item display, if i can show products this way in ng-table then my work will be easy as it has in-build paging-filtering-sorting etc